# Saving individual output lines into variables

Tags: bash, shell, output

I'm using `find -mtime -2` to find files modified in the past 24 hours or less.
The output looks like this.

```
/home/user/logs/file-2014-08-22.log
/home/user/logs/file-2014-08-23.log
```

I need to save the first line of the output to a variable and then save the second line to a separate variable. I can't just pipe it. I know you might suggest `| grep 22` or `23` but this is part of a bash script that will run many times, there will be a different set of files with different names next time so `grep` would be too specific. Could `awk` accomplish this? If so, how? .

Comment: You have two lines output, how can you save third line?

Comment: Sorry there was originally the path followed by the files. Editing now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that there are no spaces or the like in any of your filenames, there are a couple of ways of doing this. One is just to use an array:

```
files=( $(find -mtime -2) )
a=${files[1]}
b=${files[2]}
```

`files` will be an array of all the paths output by `find` in order, indexed from zero. You can get whichever lines you want out of that. Here I've saved the second and third lines into `a` and `b`, but you could use the array elements directly too.

An alternative if you have GNU find or another with the `printf` option is to use it in combination with [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
read junk a b junk < <(find -printf '%p ')
```

This one turns all of `find`'s output into a single line and then provides that line as the input to `read`, which saves the first word (path) into `junk,` the second into `a`, the third into `b`, and the rest of the line into `junk` again.

Similarly, you can introduce the [`paste` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) for the same effect on any POSIX-compatible system:

```
read junk a b junk < <(find -mtime -2 | paste -s)
```

`paste -s` will convert its input into a single tab-separated line, which `read` can deal with again.

In the general case, if you're happy to execute the main command more than once (not necessary here), you can use [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) easily:

```
find | sed -n 2p
```

That will print only the second line of the output, by suppressing ordinary output with `-n` and selecting line 2 to `p`rint. You can also stitch together `head` and `tail` for the same effect, which will likely be more efficient in a very long file.

All of the above have the same effect of storing the second and third lines into `a` and `b`, and all still have the assumption that there are no spaces, tabs, newlines, or any other characters that happen to be in your [input field separator (`IFS`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) value in any of the filenames.

---

Note though that the output order of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) is undefined, so "second file" isn't really a useful identifier unless you're organising them to be ordered some other way. It's likely to be something close to creation order in many cases, but not all.

Answer (score 5):

With `bash 4.x`, you can use [mapfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile):

```
$ mapfile -t <<< "$(find -mtime -2)"
$ printf "%s\n" "${MAPFILE[0]}"
/home/user/logs/file-2014-08-22.log
$ printf "%s\n" "${MAPFILE[1]}"
/home/user/logs/file-2014-08-23.log
```

`mapfile` reads lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable, default array is `MAPFILE`. You can specify the name of array:

```
mapfile -t array <<< "$(find -mtime -2)"
```

`-t` option cause `mapfile` remove a trailing newline from each line read.

Comment: Can you expand slightly on what mapfile actually does? (i.e. put an single line from the `man` page here)

Comment: @Bernhard: Updated answer.

Comment: Maybe I don't have bash 4.x because mapfile didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @chubby_monky: You can use `bas --version` to check.

Answer (score 1):

Without restricting your self to a known number of files found or repeated entries in code or command line , you can use the following one line (though a long one) to assign sequential variable names to each output of `find`:

The line/script:

```
$ counter=0; for log_file in $(find -mtime -2); do echo $log_file; if [ -f $log_file ]; then ((counter++)); eval var_$counter=`readlink -f $log_file`; fi; done
```

Output (as in regular `find`), if the `echo` line isn't removed:

```
.
./logs
./logs/file-2014-08-22.log
./logs/file-2014-08-23.log
```

But, here I screen for valid files using `if -f ....` option (as described [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)), and hence the desired information is preserved:

```
$ echo $counter
2
$ echo $var_1
/home/shadowe/Videos/logs/file-2014-08-22.log
$ echo $var_2
/home/shadowe/Videos/logs/file-2014-08-23.log
```

Thus, sequential variables contain the absolute path of the `find` results and can be easily incorporated with an existing script.